# Letters appearing outside plots when using multiple facet plotting with ggplot and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, data-visualization

I want to create a facet plot using both ggplot and plotly (ggplotly to be precise). Almost everything works fine. The following code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

Year <- c(2000:2008)
Name <- c('A', 'B')
Size <- rep(c('Small', 'Medium', 'Large'), each=6)
City <- c('NY', 'PARIS', 'BERLIN')
Frequency <- sample(x = c(100:1000), size = 144)
Rel_Freq <- sample(x = c(1:100), size = 144, replace = TRUE)

StackData <- data.frame(Year, Name, Size, City, Frequency, Rel_Freq)

StackData$Size <- factor(StackData$Size, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large"))
```

```
ggplotly(ggplot(StackData, aes(x= Year, y= Frequency, shape = Name, col = Name)) +
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values= c(17, 6))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#37D9E1", "#3D3D3F")) +
  facet_grid(City ~ Size, scales="free_y")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1),
        strip.text.x = element_text( size = 12, face = "bold" ), 
        strip.text.y = element_text( size = 12, face = "bold" ))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#D3D3D3", "#A9A9A9", "#696969"), guide=FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10",
                     labels = scales::unit_format(
                       unit = "", 
                       scale = 1))+
  labs(y= "",
       x= ""),
  tooltip = c("x","y","colour"),
  autosize = T, width = 680, height = 530) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE,
         margin = list(l = 0, r = 25, t = 50, b = 130),
         annotations = list(x = .5, y = -0.25, #position of text adjust as needed
                            text = "Super cool Plot",
                            showarrow = F, 
                            xref='paper', 
                            yref='paper',
                            xanchor='auto',
                            yanchor='bottom',
                            xshift=0,
                            yshift=0,
                font=list(size=9, color="black")))
```

Results in this

[image]

Like shown in the image, there is a letter showing up in the upper right corner. After some changes, I realized it is the first letter of the variable to which I redirect the color and the shapes in ggplot (in this case 'name').

How can I do get the same plot without this letter appearing there? And perhaps more interesting, why is this occuring?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That weird "N" is coming from the legend portion of your theme in ggplot:

```
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

In fact, this is quite a thorny problem. ggplotly actually does not transfer everything form ggplot correctly. There is a github issue on this topic, but I beleive that the problem persists. 
See: 
(legend.position always 'right' in ggplotly, except when legend.position = 'none'
) https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1049

In your case, the legend.position = "bottom" argument is being ignored by ggplotly.

**Option 1**:
It looks like you may not actually want the legend in the chart. In that case, you might be better off synchronizing the legend calls across ggplot and ggplotly:

```
# ggplot portion
theme(legend.position = "none")
# plotly portion:
layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

**Option 2:**
Format the legend only in plotly. From the github issue link above, this was one of the suggested ideas:

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(df, aes(year, freq, color = clas)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position = 'top')
) %>%
  layout(legend = list(
      orientation = "h"
    )
  )
```

I modified your code using option 1 and came up with the below. The weird "N" is now gone!

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

Year <- c(2000:2008)
Name <- c('A', 'B')
Size <- rep(c('Small', 'Medium', 'Large'), each=6)
City <- c('NY', 'PARIS', 'BERLIN')
Frequency <- sample(x = c(100:1000), size = 144)
Rel_Freq <- sample(x = c(1:100), size = 144, replace = TRUE)

StackData <- data.frame(Year, Name, Size, City, Frequency, Rel_Freq)

StackData$Size <- factor(StackData$Size, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large"))
StackData

ggplotly(ggplot(StackData, aes(x= Year, y= Frequency, shape = Name, col = Name)) +
           geom_point(size = 3)+
           scale_shape_manual(values= c(17, 6))+
           scale_color_manual(values = c("#37D9E1", "#3D3D3F")) +
           facet_grid(City ~ Size, scales="free_y")+
           theme_bw()+
           theme(legend.position = "none",        ## this is the only change to your code
                 panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1),
                 strip.text.x = element_text( size = 12, face = "bold" ), 
                 strip.text.y = element_text( size = 12, face = "bold" ))+
           scale_fill_manual(values = c("#D3D3D3", "#A9A9A9", "#696969"), guide=FALSE)+
           scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10",
                              labels = scales::unit_format(
                                unit = "", 
                                scale = 1))+
           labs(y= "",
                x= ""),
         tooltip = c("x","y","colour"),
         autosize = T, width = 680, height = 530) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE,
         margin = list(l = 0, r = 25, t = 50, b = 130),
         annotations = list(x = .5, y = -0.25, #position of text adjust as needed
                            text = "Super cool Plot",
                            showarrow = F, 
                            xref='paper', 
                            yref='paper',
                            xanchor='auto',
                            yanchor='bottom',
                            xshift=0,
                            yshift=0,
                            font=list(size=9, color="black")))
```

[image: Image of Modified PLot]

Comment: It was a 2 weeks (more or less) problem I have been trying to adress by looking here in SO and other pages. At the end I gave up and posted the question. Thanks for your super complete answer with both the explanation of the issue and the work-around!

Comment: Happy to help! When you get a chance, please mark the answer as "accepted". That way, when other people come across this question in the future, they will know that this problem has a solution.

Comment: Just learnt a new command in SO. Done. Answer marked. Thanks!